# Why is PHP cURL so much faster than SOAP-UI?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am using PHP 5.3.8 and Soap-UI 4.6.4 for these tests.

When I send a request in Soap-UI I see response times report by Soap-UI as 5-12 seconds.

When I perform requests using the following PHP code my requests are reliably under 5 seconds. What could account for these differences? Both the Soap-UI and the cURL URL (`$end_point`) are the same. I am calculating the PHP response time by subtracting `$start_sending` from `$end_sending`. The value of `$request` is the request string copied directly from Soap-UI.

Initially I thought it was time in calculating headers.

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($request),
    'SOAPAction: PriceSearch'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $end_point );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE );
    $start_sending = microtime( TRUE );
    curl_exec( $ch );
    $end_sending = microtime( TRUE );
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
```

EDIT: The endpoint makes use of WSO2 WSF for PHP.

Comment: It is really hard to say without understanding the difference between your two client side implementations as well as what is going on with the target endpoint.  Either way 5 seconds would be considered a very long response time for most services.

Comment: @MikeBrant That code is the implementation for one client side, the other is [SoapUI](http://soapui.org), a popular tool for testing this. The target endpoint is the same, the only thing that would cause it to behave differently would be if it reacts to SoapUI as a .NET client and has to change the response.